# Click function to be called on dynamic element

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, carousel

I have an element on my page which is feed by js library of the slider. This **a href**  is "next" button and there is no auto slide feature in the slider and I need to make that auto slide.

The next button element that is dynamically added  :

```
<div class="next">
    <a class="cmdForward" href="#"><span class="icon">
    <i class="fa fa-angle-right" title="Next page"></i></span></a>
</div>
```

to make it auto slide i wrote jquery code :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 setInterval(function() { 
    $('a.cmdForward').click();
}, 3000);
});
```

But It's not working. 
I think the issue is because of dynamic element. I guess ...

Comment: Why not use a slider that has the features you want?

Comment: This is pdf slider and there is no auto slide for pdf

Comment: Which slider do you use?

Comment: Triggering an event like that works fine as long as the element is present, it doesn't matter if it was inserted dynamically. What is supposed to happen when the `click` event is triggered, there has to be an event handler somewhere that you're trying to trigger ?

Comment: when i click on that icon in slider manually it flip to next page and so i want to do that by code in loop in certain time interval

Comment: this works in console but not in my code

Answer (score 0):

From array of links you to execute click on specific link.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
   setInterval(function() { 
      console.log('test');
      $('a.cmdForward')[0].click(); // select specific link. as jquery returns array.
  }, 3000);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="next">
    <a class="cmdForward" href="google.com">test<span class="icon">
    <i class="fa fa-angle-right" title="Next page"></i></span></a>
</div>
```

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'click' of undefined

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'click' of undefined

Comment: @shyam If the element does not exist when this code runs then you'll get that error, but it will still try again 3 seconds later.  If you continue to get the error then the element still does not exist on the page.

Comment: here is working code https://jsbin.com/tetezocoze/1/edit?html,js,output